# usage of direct strings vs creating a variable in local method

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand is there any difference (performance/best programming practice..etc) between using a direct string vs creating a temporary variable in side a method and used it exactly once. Here is an example

```
Class Sample {
   public boolean compareString(String str){
     String test = "Test";
     return test.equalsIgnoreCase(str);
           vs
     return "Test".equalsIgnoreCase(str);
   }
}
```

In my opinion, both are the same. Instead of creating a variable, one can directly use it. Please let me if there are any other differences and which one is preferred?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri that is not a duplicate.

Comment: In your example, both strings are from string pool; however, you're question leads to the one I marked as duplicate. Have a look on that.

Comment: @f1sh that is not; but in this case, it's both string literals.

Comment: To answer the question: No, there is no difference.

Comment: @f1sh that is what I meant: this question does *not* make sense, but the title "direct string vs. variable" inclines more to whatever I mentioned, and I think it will be more helpful to the OP, rather than solely "no difference" answer.

Comment: To be pedantic, there is one less line of code in the second.

Comment: Difference in what sense? Performance? Best programming practice?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri how is that marked question related in any way? This is not about the String pool.

Comment: @f1sh once again: it is not *exactly* the duplicate. What I'm saying is, that this question does *not* make sense, as there is no difference. Even syntactically both are string literals here. Title of this question, however, can be an indicator that the mentioned reference to another question might be what the OP really wants to know. If not, they'll just say - no, and that's it.

Comment: While in your case there is no difference, imagine if `test` had a chance of not being initialized. `test.equalsIgnoreCase(str)` will throw a `NullPointer`, while the other way will not.

Comment: @cela [4.3.3. The Class `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.3): "String literals (§3.10.5) are references to instances of class `String`." Also in [3.10.5. String Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5).

Comment: @JWoodchuck difference in both performance and best programming practice. imo, there is no difference in performance wise in both approaches.

Comment: @akuzminykh I am unsure of what point you are trying to convey?

Comment: @cela With what the JLS states about string literals, I think there is no chance that `test` is uninitialized. Also, I just wanted to leave these two links here for people interested in more details.

Answer (score 2):

No difference, because string literals (like `"one"`, `"two"`) are stored into **String Pool** and reused.

From your example:

```
String test = "Test";
// "Test" - string literal is stored in the StringPool
// test - reference to string literal "Test" from StringPool

return test.equalsIgnoreCase(str);
return "Test".equalsIgnoreCase(str);
// in both cases you use the same string literal stored in StringPool
```

**P.S.**

```
String str = new String("abc");
// "abc" - string literal is created (or reused) and stored in StringPool
// new String() - string object is stored in heap and contains (separate copy) of string literal "abc"
// str - reference to the string object in heap
```

In case you want to get a refernce to the string from StringPool:

```
String str1 = str.intern();
// str1 - reference to the string literal from the String Pool
```

Comment: "because strings are stored into String Pool" - wrong. Strings are stored into string pool if they're created as String literals.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the difference.

```java
String str = null;
            
String test = "Test";
boolean a =  test.equalsIgnoreCase(str);
            
boolean b =  "Test".equalsIgnoreCase(str);
```

The bytecode

```java
2  ldc <String "Test"> [16] // push the constant on stack
4  astore_2 [test]  // stores in internal list
5  aload_2 [test]   // retrieves constant, pushes on stack
6  aload_1 [str]    // target of comparison
7  invokevirtual java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String) : boolean [18]
10  istore_3 [a]     // store boolean result

11  ldc <String "Test"> [16] // push the constant on stack
13  aload_1 [str]    // target of comparison
14  invokevirtual java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String) : boolean [18]
17  istore 4 [b]     // store boolean result
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for any differences (peformance/programming practice.. etc) between 2 approaches and found that there are no differences.

2nd approach is better in best programming practice (it make sense to create a temporary variables if it is used in other places with in that method).

Comment: You should not think about "less number of lines of code" but about what the code and each line does. The solution with a temporary variable makes no sense not because it has one more line, but because the temporary variable is only used for one single statement right after.

Comment: @akuzminykh agree. in my real development example, the temporary variable is used only once right after it's declaration. it make sense to create a temporary variable if it used multiple times with in the method.

Comment: Adding a temporary variable can make sense even if it is only used once, for example if it improves readability. For the code in the question, using a static final constant would make more sense though.